# Question on Digit Meaning in Font Name

Tags: fonts

I’ve been reading about font and font families recently and one thing I’ve not found an explanation for yet is the meaning of the digit(s) in the font name. For example, in the Computer Modern font family I’ve seen `cmr10` described as the default font for the article, book, and report classes. But what does the `10` mean? Is there, for example, a `cmr12`? Is it just a version number?

I could ask a similar question regarding the Computer Modern math italic font `cmmi` (that’s a guess, I’ve not found an explanation of what the short names/designator signify either). I’ve seen a `cmmi10` listed [here](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf#page19) but in my own documents I see `cmmi12`. I can’t find an explanation of what the numbers designate.

Comment: cmr10 is designed to be used at 10pt, cmr12 is designed to be used at 12pt

Comment: the important thing to note is that Computer Modern uses _optical scaling_ so cmr12 is not the same as cmr10 scaled to 12pt, similarly cmr5 is designed to be read at small size and is a lot more legible than cmr10 scaled to 5pt.

Comment: Okay - I’m not too familiar yet with the various types of font scaling. But I will keep in mind that for Computer Modern specifically I should use cmr10 with a document with the 10pt option passed to it.

Comment: from latex you should not normally ever need to refer to these font names, if you go `\fontsize{6.5pt}{8pt}\selectfont` it will select the suitable font `cmr6` or `cmr6 scaled to 6.5pt` with the `fix-cm` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle understood, thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the name `cmr10`, the `10` indicates size (10pt) of the font. You can have `cmr12`  as well.

A complete list of different font types and sizes, have a look at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf